# Correctly Implementing Zobrist Hashing

Tags: hash, chess

I'm currently adding transposition tables in my chess engine, and I'm having issues with incrementally updating Zobrist keys. I [did some research](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Zobrist+Hashing) and implemented the basic idea, but it's not behaving as I expect. The problem I encountered was that equivalent board positions do not always have the same keys. For example, in the starting position, if both players just moved a knight and then moved it back, the key would be different from that of the starting position. However, doing this again (moving the knights) and returning to the starting position *would* result in the original key. So it seems that the period for such sequence is 4 moves for each player, when it should just be 2.

Has anyone encountered such a problem or can think of solution? I've included the relevant portions of my make/unmake methods. I don't include side-to-move, castling rights, etc; they shouldn't affect the particular case I brought up. HashValue stores the random values, with the first index being the piece type and second being the square.

```
void Make(Move m) {
    ZobristKey ^= HashValue[Piece[m.From].Type][m.From];
    ZobristKey ^= HashValue[Piece[m.From].Type][m.To];
    ZobristKey ^= HashValue[Piece[m.To].Type][m.To];
    //rest of make move
}

void Unmake(Move m) {
    ZobristKey ^= HashValue[m.Captured.Type][m.To];
    ZobristKey ^= HashValue[Element[m.To].Type][m.To];
    ZobristKey ^= HashValue[Element[m.To].Type][m.From];
    //rest of unmake
}
```

Comment: Normally make and unmake should be the same. (XOR is symmetric) The hash should not reflect moves, but pieces on the board. Capturing a piece := removing its value from the hash. Moving a piece := removing the prev position from the hash + adding the new position to the hash. (castling and en-passant state are a bit different)

Comment: Yes, I believe that's what my code does. There's also the rest of the make/unmake code that has to be taken into account, so that's why "to" and "from" squares change; the piece that was at "from" in the make method is clearly no longer there in the unmake method.

Comment: No, the Make() code should only have two components: one to remove the piece from the old postion, and one to add it to the new posisiton. (and possibly an extra component to remove a captured piece)

Comment: I have an "empty" piece type, so I assumed that I wouldn't need to check for the captured piece. I don't think it creates any problems, but it's a good idea to check.

Comment: Well, I was wrong. Including the "empty" piece screwed things up. Thanks for the help; I'll accept your answer if you make one :).

Comment: Normally, the "empty" piece just hash a Zobrist entry of zero, so you won't need to add/remove it from the hash value. Ill add some pseudo-code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Make_a_move() {
    hashval ^= Zobrist_array[oldpos][piece];
    hashval ^= Zobrist_array[newpos][piece];
    /* if there is a capture */
    hashval ^= Zobrist_array[otherpos][otherpiece];
    }

Undo_a_move() {
    hashval ^= Zobrist_array[oldpos][piece];
    hashval ^= Zobrist_array[newpos][piece];
    /* if there was a capture */
    hashval ^= Zobrist_array[otherpos][otherpiece];
    }
```

Castling can be seen as the sum of two moves (without capture, obviously)

Promotion can be treated as removing a pawn from the board (from the 2 or 7 position) and adding the new piece (at the 1 or 8 position)