# Generate unique identifier for chess board

Tags: artificial-intelligence, checksum, chess

I'm looking for something like a checksum for a chess board with pieces in specific places. I'm looking to see if a dynamic programming or memoized solution is viable for an AI chess player. The unique identifier would be used to easily check if two boards are equal or to use as indices in the arrays. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have a preference for how you store positions on the board?

Comment: maybe just bitmap it and hash.

Comment: A "unique identifier" and a "checksum" are _very_ different pieces.  checksums can be far smaller, because checksums aren't usually unique.  If you want to uniquely identify a chessboard... That's going to take a TON of space.  I just found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_number, which is an estimate.  Aproximately 10^43 to 10^50. Relevent, there's an estimated 10^50 atoms on earth.

Comment: @MooingDuck I'm not sure where you get that number from.  You can easily uniquely identify a chess-setup using eg. [forsyth notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation).

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft That takes a ton of space?

Answer (score 3):

An extensively used **checksum** for board positions is the [Zobrist signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobrist_hashing).

It's an almost unique index number for any chess position, with the requirement that two similar positions generate entirely different indices. These index numbers are used for faster and space efficient transposition tables / opening books.

You need a set of randomly generated bitstrings:

- one for each piece at each square;
- one to indicate the side to move;
- four for castling rights;
- eight for the file of a valid en-passant square (if any).

If you want to get the Zobrist hash code of a certain position, you have to `xor` all random numbers linked to the given feature (details: [here](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Zobrist_Hashing) and [Correctly Implementing Zobrist Hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067514/3235496)).

E.g the starting position:

```
[Hash for White Rook on a1] xor [White Knight on b1] xor ... ( all pieces )
... xor [White castling long] xor ... ( all castling rights )
```

`XOR` allows a fast incremental update of the hash key during make / unmake of moves.

Usually 64bit are used as a standard size in modern chess programs (see [The Effect of Hash Signature Collisions in a Chess Program](http://www.craftychess.com/hyatt/collisions.html)).

You can expect to encounter a collision in a 32 bit hash when you have evaluated √ 2<sup>32</sup> == 2<sup>16</sup>. With a 64 bit hash, you can expect a collision after about 2<sup>32</sup> or 4 billion positions ([birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)).

Comment: this is the only answer that takes advantage of hashing, but the question asks for "like a checksum" and "unique identifiers" (which I take to mean no collisions).

Comment: Yes you're right. Zobrist signatures aren't unique but many chess programs are using them exactly "to easily check if two boards are equal". They are quite safe and could be enough for the OP needs (or at least an option to take into consideration).

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a checksum, the usual solution is [Zobrist Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobrist_hashing).

If you're looking for a true unique-identifier, the usual human-readable solution is [Forsyth notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation).

For a non-human-readable unique-identifier, you can store the type/color of the piece on each square using four-bits.  Throw in another 3-bits for en-passant square, 4-bits for which castlings are still allowed, and one-bit for whose turn it is, and you end up with exactly 33 bytes for each board-setup.

Answer (score 0):

If two games achieve the same configuration through different moves or move orders, they should still be "equal". e.g. You shouldn't have to distinguish between *which* pawn is in a particular location, as long as the location is the same. You don't seem to really want to hash, but to uniquely and correctly distinguish between these board states.

One method is to use a 64x12 `square-by-piecetype` membership matrix. You can store this as a bit vector and then compare vectors for the check. e.g. the first 64 addresses in the vector might show which locations on the board contain pawns. The next 64 show locations which contain knights. You could let the first 6 sections show membership of white pieces and the final 6 show membership of black pieces.

Binary membership matrix pseudocode:

```
bool[] memberships = zeros(64*12);
move(pawn,a3,a2);

def move(piece,location,oldlocation):
    memberships(pawn,location) = 1;
    memberships(pawn,oldlocation) = 0;
```

This is cumbersome because you have to be careful how you implement it. e.g. make sure there is only one king maximum for each player. The advantage is that it only takes 768 bits to store a state.

Another way is a length-64 integer vector representing vectorized addresses for the board locations. In this case, the first 8 addresses might represent the state of the first row of the board.

Non-binary membership matrix pseudocode:

```
half[] memberships = zeros(64);
memberships[8] = 1;        // white pawn at location a2
memberships[0] = 2;        // white rook at location a1
...
memberships[63] = 11;      // black knight at location g8
memberships[64] = 12;      // black rook at location h8
```

The nice thing about the non-binary vector is you don't have as much freedom to accidently assign multiple pieces to one location. The downside is that it is now larger to store each state. Larger representations will be slower to do equality comparisons on. (in my example, assume each vector location stores a 16-bit half-word, we get 64*16=1014 bits to store one state compared to the 768 bits for the binary vector)

Either way, you'd probably want to enumerate each piece and board location.

```
enumerate piece {
    empty = 0;
    white_pawn = 1;
    white_rook = 2;
    ...
    black_knight = 11;
    black_rook = 12;
}
enumerate location {
    a1 = 0;
    ...
}
```

And testing for equality is just comparing two vectors together.

Comment: You could represent the board state in other ways, too. For example, a length-64 vector of ints from range 0-5, enumerating piece types. This should be safer than the bit vector above because you can't accidently assign multiple pieces to the same location, but it might be slower to implement equality checks.

Comment: Your description sounds like what I want but I'm still not sure what you mean by a membership matrix or how I might go about implementing it.

Comment: Also a few more bytes should be used to store values like the active color. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation

Answer (score 0):

There are 64 squares. There are twelve different figures in chess that can occupy a square plus the possibility of  no figure occupying it. Makes 13. You need 4 bits to represent those 13 (2^4 = 16). So you end up with 32 bytes to unambiguously store a chess board.

If you want to ease handling you can store 64 bytes instead, one byte per square, as bytes are easier to read and write.

EDIT: I've read some more on chess and have come to the following conclusion: **Two boards are only the same, if all previous boards since last capture or pawn move are also the same**. This is because of the threefold repetition rule. If for the third time the board looks exactly the same in a game, a draw can be claimed. So in spite of seeing the same board in two matches, it may be considered unfortunate in one match to make a certain move, so as to avoid a draw, whereas in the other match there is no such danger.

It is up to you, how you want to go about it. You would need a unique identifyer of variable length due to the variable number of previous boards to store. Well, maybe you take it easy, turn a blind eye to this and just store the last five moves to detect directly repetetive moves that could lead to a third repetion of positions, this being the most often occuring reason.

If you want to store moves with the board: There are 64x63=4032 thinkable moves (12 bits necessary), but many of them illegal of course. If I count correctly there are 1728 legal moves (A1->A2 = legal, A1->D2 illegal for instance), which would fit in 11 bits. I would still go for the 12 bits, however, as to make interpretion as easy as possible by storing 0/1 for A1->A2 and 62/63 for H7->H8.

Then there is the 50 moves rule. You don't have to store moves here. Only the number of moves since last capture or pawn move from 0 to 50 (that's enough; it doesn't matter whether it's 50, 51 or more). So another six bits for this.

At last: Black's or white's move? Enpassantable pawn? Castlingable rook? Some additional bits for this (or extension of the 13 occupancies to save some bits).

EDIT again: So if you want to use the board to compare with other matches, then "two boards are only the same, if all previous boards since last capture or pawn move are also the same" applies. If you only want to detect repetion of positions in the same game, however, then you should be fine by just using the 15 occupancies x 64 squares plus one bit for who's move it is.

Comment: Would having pawns hit the end and upgraded affect that at all?

Comment: @Something Jones: No, it is still 64 squares, each occupied by one of the twelve figures or empty. You could have 64 pawns or 32 queens or no figure at all; it doesn't matter.

Comment: Seems I was a bit too quick with my solution. As bluebaby comments his/her own answer: Two boards can *look* the same without *being* the same. Is a pawn enpassantable right now? Is a rook still castlingable? Do previous moves lead towards a draw? Is it black's or white's move? Okay, we could extend the thirteen options with "enpassantable pawn" and "castlingable rook" to get fifteen options which still fit in 4 bits. But the other things must be stored separately in addidtional bits or bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a checksum like md5, sha, just pass your chessboard cells as text, like:

```
TKBQKBHT
........
........
........
tkbqkbht
```

And get the checksum for generated text.

The checksum between one to other board will be different without any related value, at this point may be create a unique string (or array of bits) is the best way:

```
TKBQKBHT........................tkbqkbht
```

Because it will be unique too and is easily compare with others.